# Canadian tax on capital gain multiple round of investment in the same company

Tags: stocks, canada, capital-gains-tax

My question is similar to this one ([How to calculate capital gains on multiple trades of the same stock?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/139843/how-to-calculate-capital-gains-on-multiple-trades-of-the-same-stock)), but lets say I have two objective with my investment. One short term, the other one long term. I have on trading account.

Let's say I buy a few stocks of company A?? every month in my long term strategy. I've been going that for 10+ years, so my buying price varied from 1$ to 1.5$, with an average of 1.2$.

Now I have a short term objective and my strategy still involve stock of company A??. In this example I think that the stock will be worth 1.6$ next month, and it is now worth 1.5$.

How can I avoid pay large capital gain tax (e.g. capital gain on 0.4$ [1.6$-1.2$]) because I own that same stock for the long term objective. I would obviously prefer to pay the capital gain on 0.1$ (1.6$-1.5$).

Do I need to open another trading account with the same trader, with another trader? Are there other options to reduce capital gain tax by selling the units with the highest buying price?

Thanks